# Convert a string to a date with Date or Moment.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, momentjs

I have a string that I want to convert into a date to compare it to the current date and hour (local time). The string format is like this:

```
2020-06-09 11:25 pm
```

And I want to use either Date or Moment.js to format it to a `Date` object, but so far I haven't had any luck.

```
const date = new Date(`${eventDayFinish} ${eventHourFinish}`);
```

Prints `Date { NaN }`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Use the moment this way.

```
let d = moment('2020-06-09 11:25 pm', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm a').format();
console.log(new Date(d));
// Tue Jun 09 2020 23:25:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

[image]

---

> Explanation:
>   Moment takes the second argument as the format of the input date string, you can give any format to it, along with the format you passed, it will return you the date object.